# Brightcove video once appears on page load then disappear immediately in IE browser?

Tags: sitecore, brightcove

I am working with brightcove video, its working fine in firefox and chrome but in IE it appears once on page load then disappeared immediately, means video is not showing in ie browser.

What could be the reason behind this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var player;
var modVP;

function myTemplateLoaded(experienceID) {
    player = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID);
    modVP = player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);

    $('.stillimage').stop().fadeOut(150);
    $('.BrightcoveExperience').stop().fadeOut();

}

$('.video_resource_container .video_rotator .slideshow ul li:first').addClass('active-vd');

$('.video_resource_container .video_rotator .slideshow ul li input').click(function () {
    $('.video_resource_container .video_rotator .slideshow ul li').removeClass('active-vd');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active-vd');
});

function onTemplateReady(evt) {

}

function onMediaComplete(videoid, title, desc) {
    $('.video_title').empty();
    $('.video_title').html(title);
    $('.video_para').empty();
    $('.video_para').html(desc);
    modVP.loadVideoByID(videoid);        
}

</script>
```

Comment: I have solved this issue. Just remove these script $('.stillimage').stop().fadeOut(150);    $('.BrightcoveExperience').stop().fadeOut(); from myTemplateLoaded function.

Comment: Add this as an answer and then mark it as so. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved this issue. Just remove these script

```
$('.stillimage').stop().fadeOut(150); 
$('.BrightcoveExperience').stop().fadeOut();
```

from myTemplateLoaded function.